# Parent process exits when child process tries to load keras model from python script

Tags: javascript, python, keras

I'm working on an application using a keras model as a classifier. This works fine by itself, however it is when I try to pipe this data to a js script for use in the frontend/GUI part I'm running into problems. The code snippet failing is the following:
**JS**

```
const sensor = spawn('python', ['../../scripts/realtime_test.py']);
let count = 0;

sensor.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    // Parse int if it is a classification, if it isn't, it is a debugging message
    let val = parseInt(data);
    if(!isNaN(val)){
        temperatures.push(val)
    } else{
        val = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data)
        temperatures.push(val)
    }         
    console.log(count + " " + temperatures[count++]);
});
```

**python**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    openzen.set_log_level(openzen.ZenLogLevel.Off)

    # Make client
    error, client = openzen.make_client()
    if not error == openzen.ZenError.NoError:
        print("Error while initializing OpenZen library", flush=True, end='')
        sys.exit(1)

    # Scan, connect and syncronize sensors
    sensors_found = scan_for_sensors(client)
    #name, s, imu, b = connect_to_sensor(client, sensors_found[0])
    
    sensor_bank = Sensor_Bank()
    for sensor in sensors_found:
        name, s, imu = connect_to_sensor(client, sensor)
        sensor_bank.add_sensor(name, s, imu)
    #print(len(sensor_bank.sensor_arr))
    data_queue = Data_Queue(len(sensor_bank.sensor_arr))

    sync_sensors(client, sensor_bank)

    model = keras.models.load_model(f'model/models/ANN_model_{NUM_SENSORS}.h5') # FAILING HERE
    classify_thread = threading.Thread(target=classify, args=[model, data_queue], daemon=True)
    classify_thread.start()

    collect_data(client, data_queue, sensor_bank)
```

What seems to be the problem is the loading of the model. The process just exits with no error message, working perfectly fine up until the line I've marked as FAILING in the python code snippet. AFAIK the keras.load function doesn't spawn a separate process of it's own, so I don't suspect multiple processes clashing could be the culprit... Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All processes have 2 outputs: stdout and stderr. You should check if stderr contains any clue to what's going on. Add a `sensor.stderr.on('data', function(data) {console.log(data);});` to your code and see if it helps.

Comment: This worked! It was a typo in the import of the model that didn't write any error to stdout. Didn't think of adding stderr seeing as the framework we were working on threw warnings in stdout.